# Something is not adding up here? Intersection of curves.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing a 'basic' problem on the intersection of curves as part of a larger question, but something isn't quite adding up!

I'm trying to find the point of intersection of $y=\frac{1}{k}x(1-x)$ and $y=x$ and observing what happens to the intersection point as $k$ varies.

Now after a bit of algebra, I obtained the intersection points being $(0,0)$ and $(1-k,1-k)$. So if $k\in(0,1)$, then the non-origin point of intersection *should* be in the first quadrant. However, when I sketch $y=x$ and $y=0.5x(1-x)$, then the point of intersection is in the third quadrant!

What is going on? It may very well be a calculation error but I have checked my work several times already. Quite the frustration.

Comment: How are you getting $y=0.5x(1-x)$? That corresponds to $k=2$.

Comment: And there is my mistake, I had been thinking of $y=kx(1-x)$ the entire time. Good grief, cheers mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y= x$ and $ky = x(1-x)$, then $kx = x(1-x)$, which means that $x = 0$ or $k = 1-x$.